# $\text{span}(\phi_1, \cdots \phi_m) = \{\bigcap_{i=1}^m \text{null}(\phi_i)\}^0$

Tags: dual-spaces, dual-maps

Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $\phi_1, \cdots, \phi_m \in V'$. Prove that the following three sets are equal to each other.
(a) $A = \text{span}(\phi_1, \cdots, \phi_m)$
(b) $B = \left(\bigcap_{i=1}^m \text{null}(\phi_i)\right)^0$
(c) $C = \{\phi \in V' ∶ \bigcap_{i=1}^m \text{null}(\phi_i) \subseteq \text{null}(\phi)\}$

Attempt:
Proving $A \subset B$
If $\phi \in \text{span}(\phi_1, \cdots, \phi_m)$, then for any arbitrary $x \in \bigcap_{i=1}^m \text{null}(\phi_i)$, we have
$\phi(x) = \sum_{i=1}^m c_i \phi_i (x)$ for some $c_i$. As $x \in \text{null}(\phi_i)~\forall 1 \le i \le m$, We have $\phi_i(x) = 0~ \forall 1 \le i \le m$ which gives us $\phi(x) = 0$. Thus $\phi$ annihilates $\bigcap_{i=1}^m \text{null}(\phi_i)$. Thus $\phi \in B$. Which gives us $A \subset B$.

Now lets say $\phi \in B$. Then we need to construct a linear combination of $\phi_i$ which agrees with $\phi$ on all basis elements of $V$. Here's where I'm lost. How to construct this linear combination. I can take a basis $v_1 , \cdots , v_k$ of $\bigcap_{i=1}^m \text{null}(\phi_i)$ and try to define $\phi$ as $\sum \phi_i$ and it would agree on the intersection of null space but I'm not sure how I get it to agree on the extended basis of $V$.

Comment: Instead of trying to prove $B \subseteq A$ next, how about proving $B \subseteq C$ and then $C \subseteq A$?

Comment: Another way of going about this would be to look at the dimensions of those spaces and use the fact that if $U,W$ are vector spaces of the same dimension and $W\subseteq U$, then $U=W$.

Comment: Ok so proving B a subset of C is not non trivial. My attempt at proving C subset of A. Let's say all phi_i have dimension of null space = dim V - 1. So if we have a basis v1..vn of V, There is precisely one element on which any phi evaluates to non zero. If an arbitrary linear functional lies in C only one basis element is not in the null space, by definition of C, that basis element can't be in the null space of any phi_i. Which means that all of phi_i agree with that arbitrary element on which basis element to assume a non zero value on.